# leaflet-geosearch search control outside the map container

Tags: leaflet

I have followed the docs to move the searchcontrol to another div container, but doesnt work.

Html:
`<div id="findbox"></div>`

Js:

```
var searchControl = new GeoSearchControl({
    provider: provider,
    container: 'findbox',
    style: 'bar',
  });

map.addControl(searchControl);
```

Do you know how can I move the searchcontrol to findbox's div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with append and querySelector:

```
document.getElementById('findbox').appendChild(
    document.querySelector(".geosearch")
);
```

Note that calling querySelector before `map.addControl` will return `null`

Working exemple:
https://jsfiddle.net/7r81up9k/3/

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine, but the style bar doesnt seem to work.